# error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: visual-c++

Can you tell me any solution for this error below

error1:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

error2:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
```

both the errors in the same line 2

```
#ifndef _MINIMAL_SERROR_

        SError(const SError_idlrec *pRec)\\2

            { ImportData(pRec);}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot tell you because you didn't tell us what you *want* to do. Maybe (I'm guessing now) you want to define a function called `SError`. In that case you need to insert the keyword `void` as the first word in line 2.

Comment: I had to actually try that out since I believed that no function return type defaulted to int. Appearently this is only true for C, not C++ as the error message I got was: *error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int*

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you spammed a few characters into the file on accident. Specifically the `\\2`.

Happens to me all the time which is why I always mark source files that don't belong to me as read-only =)

Comment: hey i used "\\2" here in the question just for show it is the line i am having errors. That is not there in the actual code

Comment: Then you should write `//2` instead, which is a one-line comment. The backslash is interpreted by the compiler though.